# Administration menu affects theming

Tags: routes, theming, users

I'm using the Admin menu in Drupal 7. I recently started developing a Zen sub-theme for my website and discovered something annoying.

My theme's heading background is a simple 200px high image (a brown rectangle) that repeates horizontally:

`body {
  background: transparent url(../images/background.gif) repeat-x center top;
}`

I created the theme while I was logged in and achieved [this](http://drupaltesting.weebly.com/theming.html) (first image on website). Happy as I was, I logged out and noticed with anger that my lay-out had [changed](http://drupaltesting.weebly.com/theming.html) (second image on website)!

I suspect that the admin menu 'pushes' all the content on my website to the bottom, while the background stays put. Is there a way to 'push the background to the bottom' aswell, so that I don't have to log out every time to see what happened when I changed my CSS theme code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced same problem with `Zen` theme and I think there is no professional fix for that.

Although, I have used the attributes `not-logged-in` and `logged-in` class'es (which will be available in body tag) to differentiate whether or not the user is logged and placed/adjusted my css accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Most themes provide div wrapper for their main content. In Skeleton Theme it's `<div id="wrap">` Simply use it (or create it if you don't have one yet) to attach backgrounds and position elements, and tools that needs space outside it would not interfere.

Comment: I more or less solved my problem by disabling 'Adjust top margin' in the section Configuration > Administration > Administration Menu. The upper side of my icon is now covered by the toolbar, but that's not a very big deal.